# How can I use regex to match all characters including quotes?

Tags: regex

I’m trying to write a regex that will match all three of the following pattern styles:

```
[ATTACH]

[ATTACH type="full"]

[ATTACH type="full" alt="3vmw5j.jpg"]
```

“full” and “3vmw5j.jpg” in the above example will be different in the production and are only shown as examples. The regex needs to assume those will be full a-zA-Z0-9 characters with a period for the filename.

I’ve tried this, however it’s only matching the first one.

```
/\[ATTACH(?>=\w+)?\]
```

I also tried this in regex testers online and they return 3 matches, except the only one that is matched in the .rb file I’m running is still the first one.

```
/\[ATTACH(.*)?\]
```

Admittedly, I don’t use reflex very often. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which Regex implementation are you using? ECMAScript? PCRE? PREG? .NET?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/UUwQkB/1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in ECMAScript-flavour regular-expressions:

```
\[ATTACH\s*(type="(?<type>.+?)")?\s*(alt="(?<alt>.+?)")?\]
```

Try it on Regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/Z9RryV/1

The value of the `type=""` and `alt=""` attributes are stored in the named captures `type` and `alt` respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Dai has provided answer to your pattern requirement.
i think the problem is with how you are passing the pattern to your regex/re match function or object.

When you have Double Quotes in your Pattern you have to break your Pattern String in multiple parts before and after quotes and then replace Quotes (")  using CHR or CHRW (Whichever Works) Function and then concatenate and pass this string as parameter to your function.

Using @Dai s expression

Pattern = [ATTACH\s*(type=  CHR(34).toString   (?.+?)   CHR(34).toString    )?\s*(alt=     CHR(34).toString      (?.+?)   CHR(34).toString     )?]

Don't forget to remove spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match optional key/value pairs in any order,  and the value can be word chars with optional dots where the dots can not be at the start or end of the string:

```
\[ATTACH(?: \w+="\w+(?:\.\w+)*")*]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[ATTACH` Match `[ATTACH`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w+=` Match a space, 1+ word chars and `=`
  - `"\w+` Match `"` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\.\w+)*"` Optionally repeat a dot and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times if there are multiple dots
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VG9Cv5/1)

Answer (score 0):

In case you would want to match any `ATTACH` tag with or without attributes (and those attributes are not necessary the ones of your example), a simpler alternative could be:

```
\[ATTACH\b[^\]]*\]
```

**Explained:**

```
\[       # Literal '['
ATTACH   # Literal 'ATTACH'
\b       # 'Bareword' (to make sure we don't find ATTACH in [ATTACHMENT], for example)
[^\]]*   # Any non-']' character repeated 0 or more times
\]       # Literal ']'
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/u0851d/2/).